# How i can split a textview?

Tags: android, split, textview

My question in my opinion is basic. 
However i don't find information about that and how i can do this.

It is possible split a textview? Put a line in the middle of the textview?

```
      **TextView**
    ________________   
   |                |
   |________________|               
   |                |
   |________________|
```

Other thing.... Imagine that textview have height=100dip. It is possible color only the first 10% of textview? Color only the first 10dp??

Anyone can help?
Thank you four your time and help.

Comment: To color some of percent will be done with custom textview, you can use spannable to color some chars.

Comment: did you tried setting the background with 10% shade..?

Answer (score 0):

First, You can't split a TextView. But you can achieve by setting a right image as `android:setDrawableBottom="yourImage"`

Answer (score 0):

You are able to customise a `View` in Android by overrideing the `onDraw` method of that `View`.

Something you might consider would be:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // paint a line through the centre
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2, 
                    canvas.getHeight()/2, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

This would draw a line through the centre of the `View` (in your case a `TextView`). You could use the same method for your 10%/90% colouring.

Eg.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // paint a region blue
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);//or whatever colour you want
    canvas.drawRect(0, canvas.getHeight()/10, canvas.getWidth(),
                    canvas.getHeight(), paint)
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Draw rect takes the arguments:

```
canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)
```

And there are alternatives where you can pass in the actual drawing Rectangle etc.